# Preload will make font-awsome.css unable to download fonts

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-face

I use the basic way to download the CSS file, it can automatically download font files

[online example](https://jsfiddle.net/a8ux94Ls/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
```

---

When I use preload, it cannot automatically font files

- change **rel**  to **preload**
- add **as="style"**

[online example](https://jsfiddle.net/xf0Lhc45/)

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style"  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
```

**How do I use preload to download font files?**

Comment: Try using `rel="stylesheet preload"`. This should work even in browsers that don't support it, like Firefox.

Comment: Try using this `<link rel="preload" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">` and read this https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/async-css.html